Cell in css grid overflow if align-items: end is set
When I use align-items: end in my example, the content overflows and I have no idea why. I expect the same behavior as with align-items: start. I tried setting the width but I couldn't find a solution.
Here is live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zyhkev?file=index.html
Thanks for your help.


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  gap: 5px;
}

.cell {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.cell.end {
  align-items: end;
}

.ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">
    <div>Label</div>
    <div class="ellipsis">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell end">
    <div>Label</div>
    <div class="ellipsis">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell end">
    <div>Label</div>
    <div class="ellipsis">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div>Label</div>
    <div class="ellipsis">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




@DavidThomas the functioning of ellipsis is a condition here

You need to give the ellipsis class a width. Otherwise it doesnt know where to break. Try:
.ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

